# Swiftui - Zoomable Image with NavigationStack and TabView

Tags: swiftui, uikit, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-animation

I need Images to be zoomable when a user makes a magnification gesture. The use-case is identical to Instagram - when the user zooms it covers the fullscreen.

My idea is to have a ZStack that shows the image if the zoom value is greater than 1.1 but this is very error prone and causes a lot of bugs when the users zoom outside of the image.

Ideas?

```swift
struct ZoomView: View {
    
    @State var selectedTab: Tabs = .home
    @State var imgUrl: URL = URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/id/1/500/500")!
    
    @State private var zoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            
            NavigationStack {
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    
                    Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    
                    AsyncImage(url: imgUrl) { image in
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                            .frame(height: 300)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .scaleEffect(zoomFactor)
                            .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                                .onChanged({
                                    zoomFactor = $0
                                })
                                .onEnded({ _ in
                                    zoomFactor = 1
                                })
                            )
                    } placeholder: {
                        ProgressView()
                    }
                    .padding(30)
                }
                .padding()
                .navigationTitle("Zoom View")
            }
            
            
            HStack {
                ForEach(Tabs.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { tab in
                    Button(tab.rawValue) {
                        self.selectedTab = tab
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(tab == self.selectedTab ? .red : .blue)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(.top, 40)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.green)
            .opacity(zoomFactor < 1 ? 0 : 1)
            .animation(.default, value: zoomFactor)
            
            if zoomFactor > 1 {
                AsyncImage(url: imgUrl) { image in
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                        .frame(height: 300)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .scaleEffect(zoomFactor)
                } placeholder: {
                    ProgressView()
                }
                .zIndex(500)
            }
            
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
}
```